# MeetMe in asterisk AGI

Tags: asterisk, agi

I am using asterisk 13.6.0 in my centos system. I want to use **MeetMe** in agi script. But when i am writing below line, it gives me errot.

> [Mar  3 13:08:53] WARNING[15397][C-00000013]: res_agi.c:2776
>   handle_exec: Could not find application (meetme)

I have written.

> $agi->exec('meetme',"1010");

Please tell me how conference two calls using meetme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeeahh.. I got the solution by recompiling the asterisk and while compiling we should run **menuconfig** so compile the **meetme** module.